# Load image from HTML form to display in PDF with PHP (FPDF)

Tags: php, html, forms, pdf, fpdf

I would like to create a HTML form where the user can upload a picture he wants to display in a PDF using the FPDF library in PHP.

I have tried the following minimal code - (it crashes if I do not comment the line `$pdf->Image(...)`). With this, I see that I retrieve the `tmp_name` name of the file but then I don't know how to use it to display the picture in the pdf...

What am I doing wrong ? Could anybody help ?
(disclaim: I am total newbie in html/php)

any assistance would be greatly appreciated :-)

`img_form2.php` file looks like:

```
<?php

$p1_col2_logo1_path = $_FILES['p1_col2_logo1']['tmp_name'];

$c = 7.5;
$b = 3;
$o = 2.1;

require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
define('FPDF_FONTPATH', 'fpdf/font/');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',10);

$stdx = 6 + $c;

$pdf->SetXY($stdx, 40 + $c);
$pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 255);
$pdf->Cell(80, 6.5, $p1_col2_logo1_path, 0, 2); 
$pdf->SetXY($stdx, 40*3 + $c);

$width=40;
$height=40;
//$pdf->Image($p1_col2_logo1_path, 190 + $c - $width, 22 + $c - $height, $width, $height); ///? what file path should be given to Image(...) ?
$pdf->Output(); 
?>
```

`img_form2.html` file looks like:

```
 <HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <TITLE>
 </TITLE>
 </HEAD>
<BODY>
<form action="img_form2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="p1_col2_logo1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: define *crashes*, whats the error?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue so I figured I would answer the question even though it is a few months old.  `$_FILES['p1_col2_logo1']['tmp_name']` has no extension, so FPDF can't use it as an image.  So I just took the easy route and saved the image first, then inserted it into my PDF from that file location, then deleted the image from the upload folder.  Basically:

```php
$uploadpath = "/opt/bitnami/php/tmp/";  //my php upload path
$image1 = $uploadpath.basename($_FILES["p1_col2_logo1"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["p1_col2_logo1"]["tmp_name"], $image1)
$pdf->Image($image1,$Xoffset,$Yoffset,$image1width,$image1height);
unlink($image1);
```

Of course I added checks for file size, to make sure it is a `.jpg`, `.png`, or `.gif` (FPDF can only use those image file types) and then made sure it saved properly, etc.  Upload path is set in `php.ini`.